# Wrong RTTI Visibility Information and missing attributes

Tags: delphi, attributes, visibility, delphi-xe, rtti

I have in essence the following class in my application

```
TCategory = class(TAbstractionTreeItem)
  private
    fName: String;
    fParent: Integer;
    fComment: String;
  public
    procedure Default; override;
  protected
    procedure Validate(Validation: TValidation); override;
  published
    [AbstractionField]
    property Name: string read fName write fName;
    [AbstractionField]
    property Parent: Integer read fParent write fParent;
    [AbstractionField]
    property Comment: String read fComment write fComment;
  end;
```

When I now try to get information about through advanced RTTI in Delphi XE, I get as visibility information for the published properties a result that tells me they are only public and the attributes that I added are not showing up at all.

What is going on there? I already tried to validate that it is the right class that I try to analyse and that the unit that belongs to it is recompiled, when changes occur. That does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get your code provided to compile, i changed the following:

```
AbstractionField = class(TCustomAttribute)
end;

TCategory = class(TObject)
  private
    fName: String;
    fParent: Integer;
    fComment: String;
  public
    procedure Default; 
  protected
    procedure Validate(Validation: Integer); 
  published
    [AbstractionField]
    property Name: string read fName write fName;
    [AbstractionField]
    property Parent: Integer read fParent write fParent;
    [AbstractionField]
    property Comment: String read fComment write fComment;
  end;
```

Then I wrote the following code to query the visibility of the properties:

```
var
 C : TRttiContext;
 T : TRttiType;
 P : TRttiProperty;

begin
  T := C.GetType(TCategory.ClassInfo);
  for P in T.GetProperties do
  begin
     Memo1.Lines.Add(P.Name + ' ' + 
                     GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TMemberVisibility),ord(P.Visibility)) );
  end;
end;
```

My Results where (As Expected):

```
Name mvPublished
Parent mvPublished
Comment mvPublished
```

I am using Delphi XE as well, your going to have to provide more code so we can duplicate the problem.

Also make sure you check your warnings for:
[DCC Warning] UnitName.pas(LineNum): W1025 Unsupported language feature: 'custom attribute'

This is the only way to identify if an attribute is incorrectly entered and unable to be found by the compiler.

Comment: Yes, it is kinda strange, I just tryied to reproduce it in a different console application with the exact same classes, and it worked correctly, then after switching back to my original project, and cleaning up dcu files for the third time it now works there too, very mysterious. Maybe the compiler had a hickup, I don't know. But to thank you for your effort, and that valuable tipp with the attributes, I will accept this answer.

Comment: It seems in my case the compiler just gets kinda confused from time to time for some unknown reason. What seems to help is to friendly remind him of his responsibilities by putting `{$RTTI INHERIT PROPERTIES([vcPublic, vcPublished])}` on the base class of TCategory. Up until now I wasn't able to reduce the problem to simple proportions. It just only fails with my concrete whole project.